Integrating the Beta Function
As a learning exercise, I am trying to find the mean and variance of the Beta Probability Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) from first principles (i.e. Method Of Moments):
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^k] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^k f(x) dx
$$
This was quite challenging during the manipulation steps and I made several mistakes.
Here is my attempt to do this:
$$
f(\theta; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq 1
$$
$$
B(\alpha, \beta) = \int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1} (1-t)^{\beta-1} dt
$$
1) Expected Value (First Moment)
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}[\theta] = \int_0^1 \theta f(\theta; \alpha, \beta) d\theta$$
$$\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \int_0^1 \theta \frac{\theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} d\theta$$
$$\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \int_0^1 \theta^{\alpha} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1} d\theta$$
From here, we can see that:
$$\int_0^1 \theta^{\alpha} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1} d\theta = B(\alpha + 1 , \beta)$$
Using the Beta Function and Gamma Function relationship:
$$B(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}$$
$$B(x, y) = \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x + y)}$$
$$B(\alpha + 1, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 1)}$$
Using this logic:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{B(\alpha + 1, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 1)}}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 1) \Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
Since  $Γ(x+1)=xΓ(x)$, thus:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{\alpha \Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{(\alpha + \beta) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta) \Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}
$$
2) Second Moment I think many of the same properties used above we can re-use for this:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \int_0^1 \theta^2 f(\theta; \alpha, \beta) d\theta
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \int_0^1 \theta^2 \frac{\theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} d\theta
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \int_0^1 \theta^{\alpha+1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1} d\theta
$$
Again, we can see a Beta function within this integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \theta^{\alpha+1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1} d\theta = B(\alpha + 2, \beta)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{B(\alpha + 2, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
Using the same Beta-Gamma relationship:
$$
B(\alpha + 2, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 2) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 2) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2)}}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 2) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2) \Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
Using the Gamma properties again:
$$
\Gamma(\alpha + 2) = (\alpha + 1)\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2) \Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2)}
$$
$$
\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2) = (\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta) \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta)}
$$
Have I done this correctly?

PS: The first and second moments can be combined for the Variance:

$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \mathbb{E}[\theta^2] - (\mathbb{E}[\theta])^2
$$
$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta)} - \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)^2
$$
$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta)} - \frac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha + \beta)^2}
$$
$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \frac{(\alpha + 1)\alpha(\alpha + \beta) - \alpha^2(\alpha + \beta + 1)}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta)^2}
$$
Numerator:
$$
(\alpha + 1)\alpha(\alpha + \beta) - \alpha^2(\alpha + \beta + 1) = \alpha^3 + \alpha^2\beta + \alpha^2 + \alpha\beta - \alpha^3 - \alpha^2\beta - \alpha^2 =  \alpha\beta
$$
Finally:
$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta)^2}
$$
$$
\text{Var}(\theta) = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2(\alpha + \beta + 1)}
$$

You can check https://statproofbook.github.io/P/beta-mean and https://statproofbook.github.io/P/beta-var

@ Vezen Bu: thanks for this link! looks great!
